# Tensorflow Android nightly build

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, nightly-build

So I am trying to build an Android app using Tensorflow.
I'm using Android studio 3.1.3
I came across a post saying there was an issue because of which compiling org.tensorflow is not working.
It also suggested using one of the nightly builds on ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-android/
But that just shows up as not found. Does anyone know where else I can download a nightly build from

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/ has the list of all nightly builds. Doesn't look like there is an Android one based off of this list.